# Регулярное выражение на поиск и замену шаблона с цифрой - цифрой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте, нужно найти в тексте [sm:n] , где "n"= цифре и заменить данное выражение на просто цифру. Например было [sm:2], стало 2

Comment: Однотипные вопросы :(  

    preg_replace("/\\[sm:(\\d+)\\]/", "$1", $text);
Вопрос можно удалять.

Comment: +1. Но что делать. Поиск тут крайне фигово работает...

Comment: Да дело даже не в поиске- просто не могут написать простое выражение (не в укор говорю, а факт констатирую) и создают новую тему где суть одна, а выражения отличаются по минимуму.

Comment: В поиске. Если бы он был нормальный, всем бы предлагали оценить какую-нибудь [хорошую статью][1] по соответствующей теме. 

1:http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1

Comment: Годная статья, для простых выражений то что надо.

Comment: Для сложных там есть вторая часть, а еще более сложные либо сами собой придумываются, либо надо постигать дзИнь, либо обратить внимание на ремарку в файле: не стоит все подряд пытаться решить регуляркой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\[sm:(\d+)\]/','$1',$str);

'/REGEXP/'

\[
\] - экранирование скобки

\d - все цифры
\d+ - не менее одной цифры

(\d+) - запомнить число

$1 - вывести первые запомненные скобки.

$0 - строка, соответствующая всему выражению целиком
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло